# Android Intent to open new screen with picture

Tags: android

I have a app which at the moment takes a image using the camera, at the moment once the image is took it saves to a folder on the SD Card and then the same screen stays on so another picture can be took.

I am wanting it so when the image has been took and saved a new screen opens with the picture on the new screen.

I have made a new xml file `punch.xml` and java `Punch.java` and registerd them in the manifest I just cant figure out how to set the app to open a new screen with the picture that has just been took.

Im guessing it is something to do with opening a new `Intent` once the image has been saved.

**Update**

**Ok so all working now execpt getting the image to show on the next screen?**

Punch.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.punch);

    String myRef = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("filepath");
}
```

AndroidCamera.java **UPDATED TO REFLECT CODE CHANGES**

```
public class AndroidCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;
LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;

final int RESULT_SAVEIMAGE = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl 
        = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

    Button buttonTakePicture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
    buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, 
                    myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);


        }});
}

ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback(){

    public void onShutter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }};

PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback(){

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }};

PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*Bitmap bitmapPicture 
            = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);  */
        int imageNum = 0;
        Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Punch");
        imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
        String fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
        File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
        while (output.exists()){
            imageNum++;
            fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
            output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
        }

        Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
        imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);


        OutputStream imageFileOS;
        try {
            imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
            imageFileOS.write(arg0);
            imageFileOS.flush();
            imageFileOS.close();

            Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, 
                    "Image saved", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Punch.class);
        intent.putExtra("filepath",uriSavedImage);
        //just using a request code of zero
        int request=0;
        startActivityForResult(intent,request); 
    }};

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(previewing){
        camera.stopPreview();
        previewing = false;
    }

    if (camera != null){
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            previewing = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
           Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
           if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
              // This is an undocumented although widely known feature
              parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
              // For Android 2.2 and above
              camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
              // Uncomment for Android 2.0 and above
              parameters.setRotation(90);
           } else {
              // This is an undocumented although widely known feature
              parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
              // For Android 2.2 and above
              camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
              // Uncomment for Android 2.0 and above
              parameters.setRotation(0);
           }
          camera.setParameters(parameters);
          camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
      } catch (IOException exception) {
         camera.release();

       }
        camera.startPreview();

    }


public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    previewing = false;
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

Looking at the suggestion to use putExtra() how do I set and retrieve this value?

Comment: `getIntent().getStringExtra();`

Comment: Getting as above if you are using eclipse and android plugin it should show you the tooltip for putExtra(String Name, object here); So it would be something like intent.putExtra("filepath", new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/image.jpg") or whatever the string to your file location is. Then, as Merlin said above in the new new activity you make a call to the intent to get the value which you caa use in your activity like: this.getIntent().getStringExtra(filepath);

Comment: @Davos555 i kind of get what you mean but still not sure how to implement could you update your answer with the new code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are calling

```
camera.startPreview();
```

in your pictureTaken callback.

You replace it with your code from onClick and change it startActivityForResult():

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Punch.class);
    intent.putExtra("filepath",uriSavedImage);
    //just using a request code of zero
    int request=0;
    startActivityForResult(intent,request);
```

Then you can implement onActivityResult and call `camera.StartPreview()` from there.

Don't forget to setResult in your Punch activity

Comment: still dont really understand how to implement the setResult and onActivityResult

Comment: I also need to know how to set imageURi using @Davos55 answer it seems something like String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/imagesFolder"+"/filename"

Comment: OK so now im getting error for **startActivityForResult** should it not just be **startActivity**? And then i need to put **camera.StartPreview()** into Punch.java? Ive updated the question code anyway if you want to take a look?

Comment: I meant uriSavedImage ... you already get this with `Uri.fromFile(output);` so you don't need to know where it is.

Comment: You might need a request code in there ... check the documentation for how startActivityForResult works (that was a cut/paste boo-boo)

Comment: Ok thanks for all your help so far, ive got everything working except getting the image to show on the next screen just can't figure it out

Comment: So in the next screen you call `getIntent().getStringExtra("filepath");` to retrieve the path that you are passing through, then use BitmapFactiry.DecodeFile or something (check the docs) to get a Bitmap and then call setBitmap on yur ImageView to display it ... simples ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6065/discussion-between-matt-and-merlin)

Answer (score 1):

You could save a reference to the location of where the image is saved, put that in an intent to open a new activity. Start the new activity and show the image, allow the user to delete etc.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), target.class);
intent.putExtra("ImageReference", reference);
startActivity(intent);
```

Whereas target.class is the name of your activity class.

Comment: That makes sense but how can i add that into my code so it will automaticlly go to a new screen with the picture once it has been took?

Comment: I think you could add this into the onclick method for when you take your photo, after the file is saved etc. Then get the reference to the file in whatever format the reference is stored in and send this to the new activity.

Answer (score 1):

So in your code above you seem to be going about setting the intent fine. This will run immediately after taking a picture.

Obviously you will need to reference where you saved the file. Then in the new activity class you call Punch.class, you will need to do something like:-

```
String myRef = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("ImageReference");
```

This will mean that you passed the String file path from the main activity to the new Punch.class that you created. Here you can use the file path to open the image.

Comment: Ok i have updated my question its nearly there i think just need to referance the image in the AndroidCamera.java correctly just cannot figure that part out?

Comment: search for filename in your code and the File imagesFolder object. Then you put them together and you have the file path/reference.

Comment: So it would be String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/filename"+"/imagesFolder" ?